# Excel found unreadable content in [workbook name] VBA error message

Tags: excel, vba

I get an error message that is annoying me for a long time and could not fix it. 
I am writing a code in VBA Excel. Suddenly I got the following message:
Excel found unreadable content in [workbook name]. then it asks me do you want to recover the content?
Please help me to solve this,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The following article by Microsoft addresses this issue.  They list the possible causes as:

-The workbook contains a PivotTable that uses key performance indicators (KPIs).
-The KPIs are created in the Analysis Services Business Intelligence Development Studio.
-One or more of the KPIs have an expression in the Current Time Member property.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929766

Comment: thanks Michael. I am not using a pivot table though. I noticed this issue exists when I add new ranges to the spreadsheet. for example if i name a range B2:B7 as anything, the error message appears and when i remove this range < the error message is gone. I still don't know why